# How to create database on the disk with enough space in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to import data into a database on aws. But the space is always not enough. I created the database using this command `sudo -u postgres createdb ~/data/word2vec/AidaDB -O MyName` and tried to import the data into the database using this command:
`bzcat AIDA_entity_repository_2014-01-02v10.sql.bz2 | psql /home/ubuntu/data/word2vec/AidaDB`. 
Here is the disk usage:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       89G   84G  343M 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  848K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G   76K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/xvdg       138G   60M  131G   1% /home/ubuntu/data/glove
/dev/xvdf       246G   32G  203G  14% /home/ubuntu/data/word2vec
```

Why the disk is not enough? The data is 31GB. But I thought I created the database in `/home/ubuntu/data/word2vec`. Is there a way to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify the location of the database as part of the name of the database. PostgreSQL always creates the database in it's data directory. However you could create an additional tablespace and create your database within this tablespace.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE mydbspace LOCATION '/home/ubuntu/data/word2vec';
CREATE DATABASE AidaDB OWNER MyName TABLESPACE mydbspace;
```